# AngularJS routig with jquery mobile doesn't work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I used angularjs and phonegap tools together in my application.
It works great and i never face any issue while converting app into ios or apk. but when i trying to used jquery mobile within my applications it doesn't work. i read question about this, posted on stack overflow and trying to understand answer given by experienced people. but i can't found any minimal solutions for that. so please help me, what is the best way to implement application using angularjs, jquery and mobile jquery. Give me some important links where i found best solutions for that. [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137501/angular-js-with-jquery-mobile)

### **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Project Structure</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/ngStorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/trackVehicleCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/complaintCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/commentCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/plannerCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/factory/complaintService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/factory/commentService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/factory/loginService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/factory/shareData.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="view">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['sanskritiSchool']);
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

### **app.js**

```
angular.module("sanskritiSchool", ["ngRoute", "ngStorage"])

    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when("/login", {
                templateUrl: "views/login.html",
                controller: "mainCtrl"
            })
            .when("/categoryMenu", {
                templateUrl: "views/categoryMenu.html",
                controller: "mainCtrl"
                }
            })                
            .when("/trackVehicle", {
                templateUrl: "views/trackVehicle.html",
                controller: "trackVehicleCtrl"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/categoryMenu"
            });
    }
])
```

### **categoryMenu.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cmplLogoHeader">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-1" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="cmplLogo"><a ng-href="#/categoryMenu" class="btnHome"><span class="fa fa-university"></span></a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-2" style="text-align:center">
            <h2 class="cmplLogo">SRGS</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2" style="text-align:center">
            <a href="#" class="logout" ng-click="logout()"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainCategory row" style="margin-top:80px;">
    <div class="1 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 removePadding">
        <button type="button" class="btn btnCategory" ng-click="getComplaints()"> 
            <span ng-show="!showComplaints"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o spinning"></i></span>
            <span ng-show="showComplaints"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
            Complaints
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="2 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 removePadding">
        <button type="button" class="btn btnCategory" ng-click="getPlanner()"> 
            <span ng-show="!planner"><i class="fa fa-calendar spinning"></i></span>
            <span ng-show="planner"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            Planner
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="3 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 removePadding">
        <a class="btn btnCategory" ng-href="#/trackVehicle"> 
            <span ng-show="!aa"><i class="fa fa-history spinning"></i></span>
            <span ng-show="aa"><i class="fa fa-history"></i></span>
            Track Vehicle
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="4 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 removePadding">
        <button type="button" class="btn btnCategory" ng-click="getTimetable()"> 
            <span ng-show="!timetable"><i class="fa fa-arrows spinning"></i></span>
            <span ng-show="timetable"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span>
            Timetable
        </button>
    </div>
```

When i update my index.html and trying to run app, it doesn't run.

### Updated index.html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.mobile.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```